# Possible to pull data from Tableau published Data Source without Tableau Desktop?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Besides TabPython, is there some programming language or tool outside of Tableau Desktop/Prep that can be used to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tableau Prep to connect to the published data source and ingest the data in excel/csv or database table

Comment: https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_connect.htm